Generating astronomically many strings
Is it possible to generate all possible 64-character strings using only the characters '0'-'9' and 'a'-'f' in any programming language?
The range mentioned represents an unsigned integer with an astronomically large number of possible values. The sheer magnitude of this number makes it impractical to iterate through all those values within a reasonable timeframe, even with the most advanced computers currently available.
Do you have any other creative alternative solutions in mind?
For example(hex.js)
async testing() {
    let start_point =
      "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
    const end_point =
      "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff";
    let hex_num;
    let decimal;
    let i = 1;
    while (start_point !== end_point) {
      hex_num = start_point.toUpperCase().padStart(64, "0");
      decimal = BigInt("0x" + start_point) + BigInt(1);
      start_point = decimal.toString(16).padStart(64, "0");
      console.log(`[index-${i++}]:`, hex_num);
    }  
}

Try to output all value between "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" to "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff" by programming language.
You can use any library / api technology.

If I understand correctly, your question is: "I want to do something impossible. Does anyone have any ideas that are possible?" And yes, there are infinitely many possible things that you could do instead of your impossible thing; the problem is, you've provided no constraints or guidelines whatsoever, so no one here has any of knowing which of those possible things you might be happy with.

The sheer magnitude of this number makes it impractical to iterate through all those values within a reasonable timeframe, even with the most advanced computers currently available ... you had better get started and not waste any more time .... !

(Not to put too fine a point on it, but: suppose that my "creative alternative solution" is just to write a Hello World program. Everyone loves Hello World programs! Would you be happy with that answer? If not, why not?)

What are you trying to accomplish?  You've admitted that doing thing A is impossible, so what other thing B are you hoping to do?  For example, generate 100 random 64-character hex strings?  (If so, how random?  rand() random or closer to true random?  It might help to read [tour] and [ask] then edit your question to be something we might be able to answer.
